# What's the best way to install a standalone djangopypi?

Tags: django

I would like to install a [djangopypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangopypi/) server for our local development and deployment. However, I'm slightly confused about its installation docs. Apparently, it's assumed that djangopypi is installed inside a bigger project as an app, which is at least debatable from my point of view. I would like my local PyPI instance to run independently of anything else, as a "normal" web service.

And this is where I'm lost. It seems I need some kind of a minimal Django project to wrap `djangopypi`, which seems a bit overkill for me. Is there a more elegant way to install it in standalone mode?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what you need. `djangopypi` is just an app. Like any Django app, it needs to know stuff like how to connect to your database, etc. That information comes from the project. It doesn't provide this for you because there's no way it could possible know what the best settings are for your particular environment; that's your responsibility.

So, no, it's not "overkill". It's the bare minimum required for functionality, and it's just the way things are. Create a simple project, change all the relevant items in settings.py, nclude `djangopypi`'s urls.py in yours, and you're done. Is is really that hard?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's not hard, but I rather expect some kind of standalone functionality in an app that is certainly designed to be working independently of other apps. In my world, it'd need to bring its own `wsgi.py`, include a default `settings.py`, which would point to a SQLite database and `djangopypi.urls` as the `urls.py`. In that case, I'd install a `virtualenv` containing only `djangopypi` and deps, point `mod_wsgi` to the `wsgi.py` and set up `djangopypi.settings` as a settings module. Then, so I hope, a minimal installation would work.Will try to patch it this way now.